# Unauthorized response with valid token

Tags: laravel, rest, api, ionic-framework, ionic3

I get unauthorized as response on every request after login successfully

this is some of my code (let me know if you need to see anything else):

Data provider on ionic

```
this.storageProvider.getToken().then(results => {
                      this.httpOptions = {
                      headers: new HttpHeaders({
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + results,
                          'Accept': 'application/json',
                        })
                      };
                  });

public getTodayReservations() {
  //all reservations (not todays only)
    let _url = this.url + '/guides/reservations/all';
    return this.http.get(_url, this.httpOptions);
}
```

an this the config of my laravel api routes:

```
Route::prefix('v1')
->group(function () {

    Route::post('login', 'Api\UsersController@login');

    Route::middleware('auth:api')
        ->prefix('guides')
        ->group(function () {

            Route::get('/show', 'Api\UsersController@show');

            Route::get('/reservations/today', 'Api\ReservationsController@today');
            Route::get('/reservations/all', 'Api\ReservationsController@allRes');

        });
});
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI.....
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:8100
Referer: http://localhost:8100/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can `this.storageProvider.getToken()` return a promise and not a token.

try something like this :

```
export class HttpService {

  private httpOptions;

  constructor(){
   this.storageProvider.getToken().then(results => {
        this.httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + results,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
          })
        };
    });   
  }
```

Comment: still have the same message error even if now my request header now is: Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI......
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:8100
Referer: http://localhost:8100/

Answer (score 0):

Check response of `this.storageProvider.getToken()`, usually it has `access_token` key which you are supposed to use in order to authroize your app so your code, not the full promise so your code will be like:

```
this.storageProvider.getToken().then(tokenObject => {
    private httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders(
            {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokenObject.access_token,
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            }
        )
    }; 
});
```

Of course, in your case, it might be some other key, that is why you should have a look at `this.storageProvider.getToken()` first and only send the actual access token when sending `Authorization` header.

Comment: were i should add this in the constructor ?

Comment: Where you have `httpOptions` defined, just replace your code with this one

Comment: cant do it like that cuz it a class an httpOptions in my case an attribute

Comment: initiate the attribute(its a property actually) with NULL and then in constructor put the code to populate that property, of couse then you will use `this.httpOptions = `

Comment: it works but still same error "unauthorized" check my new code I edited the post

Comment: dude :) whats in your results? can you please post that? otherwise, you are literally doing the same thing

Comment: Please make login again and use a new token, its possible that old one has expired, usually tokens have 1 hour expiry time

Comment: how can i renew it ?

Comment: simply logout and login again? you must have some code in place which renews the localstorage on each login right?

Comment: yes on logout i clear up the storage but I get the same response "{"message":"Unauthenticated."} " every time even if the token is valid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196575/discussion-between-s4l4h-and-learner).