# Request headers being ignored by Apache server

Tags: laravel, apache, rest, api, ionic-framework

I posted earlier this post right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57074630/unauthorized-response-with-valid-token/)

The problem is that when i send my requests after login on my ionic app a have the token stored and I use it to send other request that needs authentication these request has the header like this:

```
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI.....
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:8100
Referer: http://localhost:8100/
```

An after 3 days of search I figured out the request headers are being ignored by Apache and all requests arrives without token so i get this message error as response from all API routes:

```
{"message": "Unauthenticated"}
```

Comment: It's highly unlikely that Apache is dropping the headers.

Comment: @ceejayoz how to fix it ?

Comment: Debug to figure out the actual issue. Start by having your Laravel app do `print_r(Request::headers())` and see if they're there.

Comment: @ceejayoz the headers never reach the php section that's the problem they are being ignored or cut from the header

Comment: 1. Show us how exactly you've confirmed that. 2. If true, that would indicate some sort of unusual setup or custom configuration, which you'd need to show, because it's definitely not normal, out-of-the-box behaviour.